# Quantity subtraction on multiple db records execute only in case all conditions are fulfilled

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a home project where i have a stock and i need to transfer products from one table to another. The trick is that each product is made of multiple other products from diferent tables:

For example: I define that **Product A** (will be moved to table u2) is made of:

10pcs of **Product B** from table u1
 5pcs of **Product C** from table u1

Based on this when i select **Product A** from a select box and hit a transfer button the defined products need to be subtracted from the database and added or updated as a record in u2 table (**Product A**). The thing is not all products will have the defined quantity for them in that case i can throw an error, in the other case if the subtraction reaches 0 then i need to remove the respective product from the database.
 Because this is a web application i don't know what will happen when multiple users will interact with this. If i make the selects and based on those selects make updates later i don't really know for sure if another user inserted or removed records from the definitions table meanwhile so the updates will fail.

Ideally i would need to make the updates only if all the definitions have enough quantity to subtract from. I looked at TRANSACTIONS but i'm not really sure how to implement them.

Thanks for help!